# Java BinaryOperator and factory method. How to return the first parameter?

Tags: java, lambda, collections, java-8, java-stream

I was trying to convert my stream to map by the next code:

```
Collectors.toMap(City::key, Function.identity(), (first, second) -> first)
```

My question about the last lambda.

```
(first, second) -> first
```

I often need to get ***any*** element or always the ***first*** element if a collision happens.
I understand, that is already short and clear form. But still. For the `Function` class, we have the factory method `Function.identity()` which returns the passed parameter as is. Do we have the factory method for `BiFunction` or for `BinaryOperator`? Or maybe something close to `Function.identity()`.
I also know about `BinaryOperator.minBy()` and `BinaryOperator.maxBy()`, but they are more *"verbose"* and not so clear methods than `Function.identity()`.

Comment: Well, isn't a short ad hoc lambda good enough?

Comment: I don't know of any such method but you should be able to provide your own. Why don't you try it?

Comment: Also, if there is nothing specialized like that right in the standard library, wouldn't it worth be easy to create a new one? Come on, these are trivial.

Comment: There is no such method in the standard Java library, as far as I know. This could be for several reasons, including *1* the Java designers forgot, *2* they could not logically decide which one should be returned (first or second?), *3* they disagree with you about how "often" this is used, and thought it would be of little value.

Comment: Yes, I think all your answers are correct, thank you for your suggestions. I was looking for something in the standard library, but, apparently, there is nothing similar here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could easily declare your own methods:

```java
public class BinaryOperators {
    
    public static <T> BinaryOperator<T> first() {
        return (first, second) -> first;
    }

    public static <T> BinaryOperator<T> second() {
        return (first, second) -> second;
    }

    public static <T> BinaryOperator<T> any() {
        return (first, second) -> ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextBoolean() ? first : second;
    }

}
```

and then use them in your code:

```java
Collectors.toMap(City::key, Function.identity(), BinaryOperators.first())
```

with static imports:

```java
Collectors.toMap(City::key, identity(), first())
```

---

Or just do not bother with the code above and use `(a, b) -> a`:

```java
toMap(City::key, identity(), (a, b) -> a))
```

Pretty clear and concise, IMO

Comment: And of course: `public static <T> BinaryOperator<T> surpriseMe() { return (a, b) -> ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextBoolean() ? a : b; }`